# Trigger a function when Like Button on top of a page clicked

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm writing FBML code for my tab on my fan page and I want the visitors see only an image on that Welcome Tab since they click "Like" button on top of the page, just next to page name. When users like my page, then I'll show a content in that tab.

I'm trying to do something like this:
http://www.facebook.com/901Tequila?v=ap … 4904458780

I just don't know how I know my like button is pressed. Obviously, I cannot use: "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',..." in FBML and I don't know if there is FBJS equivalent of this function.

If there is a way to do this, I'm willing to hear. Thanx

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Would be great, have the same problem.